# android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText() on application click button

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I have a problem with this code

```
public class AgendaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DbManager db=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.agendalayout);
    db=new DbManager(this);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.addxml, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
            return true;

        case R.id.action_add:
            final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);

            d.setTitle("Prova");
            d.setCancelable(false);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.popupdialog);
            Window window = d.getWindow();
            window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            d.show();

            //eventi Button
            Button b = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.ok_action);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {


                    EditText p1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ora_inizio);
                    EditText p2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ora_fine);
                    EditText p3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pause);

                    String p1Value = p1.getText().toString();
                    String p2Value = p2.getText().toString();
                    String p3Value = p3.getText().toString();

                    try {
                        int p1Final = Integer.parseInt(p1Value);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast exceptionAgenda = Toast.makeText(AgendaActivity.this,
                                "Uno dei due campi o entrambi sono vuoti!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        exceptionAgenda.show();
                    }

                    //db.save(primoValore,secondoValore,terzoValore);
                }
            });

        default:
    }
    return true;
};
}

                }
            });

            Button b2=(Button) d.findViewById(R.id.canceldialog);
            b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(d.getContext(), "cliccatocancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    d.cancel();
                }
            });
```

The problem is when I click the button Ok_action this error: **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference**.  I think the problem is on the line `String p1Value = p1.getText().toString();` and I don’t know how to resolve. Can someone help me?

add an output error:

```
11-06 13:03:24.747 16356-16356/com.apps.giak.lavorotime E/AndroidRuntime:         FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 13:03:24.747 16356-16356/com.apps.giak.lavorotime E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.apps.giak.lavorotime, PID: 16356
11-06 13:03:24.747 16356-16356/com.apps.giak.lavorotime E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
11-06 13:03:24.747 16356-16356/com.apps.giak.lavorotime E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.apps.giak.lavorotime.AgendaActivity$1.onClick(AgendaActivity.java:62)
11-06 13:03:24.747 16356-16356/com.apps.giak.lavorotime E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5155)
11-06 13:03:24.747 16356-16356/com.apps.giak.lavorotime E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20747)
11-06 13:03:24.747 16356-16356/com.apps.giak.lavorotime E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-06 13:03:24.747 16356-16356/com.apps.giak.lavorotime E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-06 13:03:24.747 16356-16356/com.apps.giak.lavorotime E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
11-06 13:03:24.747 16356-16356/com.apps.giak.lavorotime E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
11-06 13:03:24.747 16356-16356/com.apps.giak.lavorotime E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-06 13:03:24.747 16356-16356/com.apps.giak.lavorotime E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-06 13:03:24.747 16356-16356/com.apps.giak.lavorotime E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteIn
```

XML

```
`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/Ora_inizio"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789./"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="Ore" />
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/Ora_fine"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:hint="data"/>

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789./"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:hint=""/>

 <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/ok_action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:text="Ok"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/canceldialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Cancel"/>
</TableRow>
```

`

Comment: Where is your element of R.id.Ora_inizio?

Comment: post your xml file here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use

`EditText p1 = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.Ora_inizio);`

instead of

`EditText p1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ora_inizio);`

Because the view with id `R.id.Ora_inizio` is in the layout which inflated to the dialog, i.e, `R.layout.popupdialog`.

> So you have to use `Dialog.findViewById()` method.

But now you are trying to access this `Edittext` from your activity layout `(R.layout.agendalayout)` instead of the dialog layout.

Comment: oh thanks now when click button ok dont crash but in the log doesn't show any action

Comment: @giacomolorenzo You haven't logged anything in the button click. What is the expected result when button is clicked?

Comment: yes im forgot to add another code but now its work and thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can tell--without even looking at your source code--what the problem is, just by the error message, and the line you stated. p1 is null; and you tried running `getText()` on it. Null doesn't have a method `getText()`, so you get a null pointer exception.

`findViewById(R.id.Ora_inizio)` likely is returning null, meaning Android had trouble finding the view by that ID in the current layout. Double check that this ID is used for a view in the current layout.

Comment: i have add an output of android monitor and added the XML